# Conditional count and add count to column

Tags: r

I have the following Data frame:

```
[]   Group  State       County     Deaths

[1]  01     Nicaragua   County A   0 
[2]  01     Nicaragua   County B   13  
[3]  01     Nicaragua   County C   0
[4]  02     Mexico      County D   0 
[5]  02     Mexico      County F   4  
[6]  02     Mexico      County E   0
```

I would like to **count all the cases** from the **same Group** where **Death is 0**, and then add the cresult as a new column. The result would ideally look like this:

```
[]   Group  State       County     Deaths  Counties.without.Deaths  

[1]  01     Nicaragua   County A   0       2
[2]  01     Nicaragua   County B   13      2
[3]  01     Nicaragua   County C   0       2
[4]  02     Mexico      County D   0       3
[5]  02     Mexico      County F   0       3  
[6]  02     Mexico      County E   0       3
```

Is there a specific function for that? I tried using loops, but as a beginner failed miserably. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Counties.without.Deaths = sum(Deaths == 0))
```

Instead of `sum`, you could also use `length(Deaths[Deaths == 0])`, however it may be slightly slower.

You could also do it in `base`, without additional packages; this would be the fastest option:

```
df$Counties.without.Deaths <- with(df, ave(Deaths, Group, FUN = function(x) sum(x == 0)))
```

A quick benchmark shows that `base` option can be almost 10 times faster:

```
Unit: microseconds
  expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
 dplyr 1056.020 1091.3915 1267.1185 1121.2920 1318.019 2294.364   100
  base  113.771  132.9145  182.4703  149.6885  170.291 2769.136   100
```

Output for both `dplyr` and `base`:

```
  Group     State   County Deaths Counties.without.Deaths
1     1 Nicaragua County A      0                       2
2     1 Nicaragua County B     13                       2
3     1 Nicaragua County C      0                       2
4     2    Mexico County D      0                       3
5     2    Mexico County F      0                       3
6     2    Mexico County E      0                       3
```

Comment: Thank very much! looked at the dplyr version. Runs without problems, but it somehow does not show up in the data frame. Only in the console.

Comment: You're welcome! You need to assign it - I've made an edit, take a look.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that worked. But somehow all rows shows the same result. I think you might have missed a condition in the dplyr version: Count the 'Death' == 0 only within a 'Group'. Your code provides me, I think, the count for all the rows (and all the Groups).

Comment: @Chronicle, not sure about that - it runs fine for me, I've included `group_by` from the beginning.

Comment: You can also check the `base` version with `ave` as this will be faster.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! It worked with the base R method. Now, I feel sorry for bothering you with my mistakes. There are just so many function, I have to still learn.

Comment: No problem, we're all learning! Consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, and upvoted your answer, but it won't show because I am new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
merge(df, aggregate(Deaths ~ Group, df, FUN = function(x) sum(x == 0)), by = "Group", suffixes = c("", "counties.without"))

  Group     State   County Deaths Deathscounties.without
1     1 Nicaragua County A      0                      2
2     1 Nicaragua County B     13                      2
3     1 Nicaragua County C      0                      2
4     2    Mexico County D      0                      3
5     2    Mexico County F      0                      3
6     2    Mexico County E      0                      3
```

**Data**:

```
df <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), State = c("Nicaragua", 
"Nicaragua", "Nicaragua", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico"), County = c("County A", 
"County B", "County C", "County D", "County F", "County E"), 
    Deaths = c(0L, 13L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That is very neat and you are extremely fast! Exceptional! I am having a small problem: The code runs, but does not add an additional column to the data frame. Perhaps it was my mistake: I am not sure what to add as x in  `FUN = function(x) sum(x == 0)`. I so far left it unchanged.

Comment: You need to assign the output: `df_new <-  merge(df, aggregate(Deaths ~ Group, df, FUN = function(x) sum(x == 0)), by = "Group", suffixes = c("", "counties.without"))`